# First occurrence in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

What regex can I use in place of `regex` in the code:

`"<tr><td>Total</td><td class=\"bar\">561 of 931</td><td class=\"ctr2\">40%</td><td class=\"bar\">38 of 58</td><td class=\"ctr2\">34%</td><td class=\"ctr1\">58</td><td class=\"ctr2\">94</td>"
.scan(regex).last`

to get `"40%"` (the first percentage figure) without modifying any other part of the code above?

Comment: That returns 34% as the code says last element of the group.

Comment: This works: `^[\S\s]+?\K\d+%`.  Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aR5cU0/1.  Catches everything from the start up until the percentage, then reset the matching, then capture the percentage

Comment: Perfect...this worked for me!! Thanks RedLaser. :)

Comment: thanks for modifying the question sawa! 
my taxi was waiting outside and had only 2 mins to post the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
regexp = /\A.*?(\d+%)/

matches = "<tr><td>Total</td><td class=\"bar\">561 of 931</td><td class=\"ctr2\">40%</td><td class=\"bar\">38 of 58</td><td class=\"ctr2\">34%</td><td class=\"ctr1\">58</td><td class=\"ctr2\">94</td>".scan(regexp).last
puts matches
#=> 40%
```

Explanation: `\A` matches the beginning of the string, `.*?` matches everything *non-greedy* and `(\d+%)` finally matches the number and the percentage sign.